# Silverlight Business Template | Authentication (User, Roles) | WCF Services | Not WCF RIA

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, authentication, role

I am using Silverlight Business Template for creating a Silverlight application. I have multiple services (WCF Plain, not WCF RIA). When we create Silverlight Business Template type application, we get login stuff (more like boilerplate code). I want to make use of it with my plain WCF services. I need to do the authentication (User Login, Role Management) while using the Services I have in place. How can I do that? Is it some realistic scenario. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this Manually:

- Hide your navigation links in the login page.
- After user press login button test the User-password and return the role
- when the role of the user is returned to the client do the following:
- Enable the required links for the role
- Navigate via the code to the appriate page.

Good Luck,
Lior